# Trying to create an application to pick up text on a timer but files are in use and timer doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, .net

I am trying to create a 'chat' application in VB.Net and - being rather new to programming - I am struggling with two issues that are preventing my program from running.

The main purpose of the program is to create a file called Chat_Server.txt that the user can create/open. The text from this file is then written to the first textbox (called server_text). At any point the user can also type text into the second textbox (called client_text) and press a 'Send' button this then writes to the Chat_Server.txt the contents of the box.

The main goal of this program is that two or more copies can be running on different computers and communicate over a shared network without having to go to an external server.
My first problem is that the program can’t open the file. Visual Studio says that the file is being used by another process.

My second problem is that the text in the server_text textbox isn't updating as soon as the other users on different computers press the send button. I tried to overcome this by using a timer and even this isn't working for some reason. I've also tried fileSystemWatcher and that doesn't work either.

Here's my code (Bearing in mind this is a form, not a console):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Chat

Dim file_name As String

Sub Chat_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Sub Create_Server_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Create_Server.Click 'This is a button on the form that get the user to choose a location to save the Chat_Server.txt

    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()    'Save the file
    SaveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
    file_name = SaveFileDialog1.FileName()  'Get the file path
    MsgBox("Server file made.")

End Sub

Sub Connect_Server_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Connect_Server.Click   'Another button on the form that gets the user to choose the Chat_Server.txt

    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()    'Open the file
    file_name = OpenFileDialog1.FileName()
    Dim fileExists As Boolean   'Tests whether the file existx and whether it works or not
    fileExists = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(file_name)
    If fileExists = True Then
        Try
            Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can't load the file. Try again.")
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Chat can't seem to find the chat file. Make sure it is called Chat_Server.txt and it is on an accessible network.")
    End If

End Sub

Sub Server_Text_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Server_Text.TextChanged

    Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox

End Sub

Sub Chat_Text_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Chat_Text.TextChanged

    Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox

End Sub
Sub Chat_Text_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Chat_Text.KeyUp   'Another textbox that holds the text that the user wants to send to the Chat_Server.txt

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then  'When the user presses enter the send button is clicked
        Send.PerformClick()
        Chat_Text.Clear()
        Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox
    End If

End Sub

Sub Send_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Send.Click

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(file_name, vbCrLf & Chat_Text.Text, True)   'When send button clicked, write all contents of Client_Text to the Chat_Server.txt
    Chat_Text.Clear()
    Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox


End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Every 100 miliseconds, places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox

End Sub
End Class
```

I would be so grateful if you could help with this, its been troubling me for weeks now.

Thanks,
08robertsj

Comment: The structure of your code is not too clear (and I have taken just a quick look at it), but I see two "issues": the Timer is not started/stopped anywhere (if you haven't set the enable property to true in the properties window, it wouldn't start), but also is reading a file every 100 ms!? without any kind of checking! (sounds too quick and too dangerous). The other issue I have seen is that you are reading and writing files from many different places too quickly, most of the time without checking anything (from textChanged events, from click events, etc.). Lots of things to improve here.

Comment: PS: we are not in the 90's anymore, people assumes by default that your program is a form, not a console ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other answer said, you need to remove that line. You also need to create the file properly and dispose after (so that handles are released). Also, set your timer to something lower like 1000ms. I also created a boolean variable to check if the connection has been made before the file is read by the timer. Remember to check that your timer is enabled in the settings.

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim file_name As String
    Dim connected As Boolean

    Sub Chat_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Sub Create_Server_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Create_Server.Click 'This is a button on the form that get the user to choose a location to save the Chat_Server.txt

        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()    'Save the file
        'SaveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        file_name = SaveFileDialog1.FileName()  'Get the file path
        SaveFileDialog1.Dispose()
        File.Create(file_name).Dispose()
        MsgBox("Server file made.")
        connected = True

    End Sub

    Sub Connect_Server_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Connect_Server.Click   'Another button on the form that gets the user to choose the Chat_Server.txt

        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()    'Open the file
        file_name = OpenFileDialog1.FileName()
        Dim fileExists As Boolean   'Tests whether the file existx and whether it works or not
        fileExists = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(file_name)
        If fileExists = True Then
            Try
                Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Can't load the file. Try again.")
            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("Chat can't seem to find the chat file. Make sure it is called Chat_Server.txt and it is on an accessible network.")
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub Server_Text_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Server_Text.TextChanged

        Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox

    End Sub

    Sub Chat_Text_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Chat_Text.TextChanged

        Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox

    End Sub
    Sub Chat_Text_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Chat_Text.KeyUp   'Another textbox that holds the text that the user wants to send to the Chat_Server.txt

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then  'When the user presses enter the send button is clicked
            Send.PerformClick()
            Chat_Text.Clear()
            Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub Send_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Send.Click

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(file_name, vbCrLf & Chat_Text.Text, True)   'When send button clicked, write all contents of Client_Text to the Chat_Server.txt
        Chat_Text.Clear()
        Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox


    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If connected Then
            Server_Text.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file_name)    'Every 100 miliseconds, places the text from Chat_Server.txt into the main textbox
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

If you want to make a proper program, you should check out TCP examples in VB.NET. Here is a tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38914/A-TCP-IP-Chat-Program

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the file ( `SaveFileDialog1.OpenFile()` ). This causes WriteAllText to fail, because WriteAllText opens and closes the file automatically.